# Problem when clicking button again in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a comment page that has a reply and cancel reply button. Using the following code when the reply button is clicked the cancel reply button will appear instead. There is only one problem, when the reply button of one comment is clicked, without clicking the cancel reply button of that comment I click the reply button of another comment, the reply button of the previous comment disappears. My level of knowledge of JavaScript is low. The code above solves all my needs, there is only one problem that I said, the code should be edited so that it does not destroy my other needs.

```
<script>
    jQuery( function( $ ){
        $( '.comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
            var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
            commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').hide();
            $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();
        } );
        $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
            var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
            commentContainer.find('#cancel-comment-reply-link').insertAfter(this).hide();
            commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').show();
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't `commentContainer.find('#cancel-comment-reply-link')` the same as `$(this)`? So you're inserting the element after itself.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: And in the first click handler, `commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link')` is the same as `$(this)`.

Comment: Please add the tag related to jQuery in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of **Jack** and **[existentia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76140452/21663731)**, I was able to solve my problem after a few days of effort.

```
<script>
    jQuery( function( $ ){
        var replyClicked = false;
        $( '.comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
        var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
        if ( ! replyClicked && $('.comment-reply-link').is(":visible") ) {
            commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').hide();
            replyClicked = true;
        } else {
            $('#cancel-comment-reply-link').parent().find('.comment-reply-link').show();
            commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').hide();
        }
        $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();
        } );
        $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
            var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
            commentContainer.find('#cancel-comment-reply-link').insertAfter(this).hide();
            commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').show();
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the issue you are facing is the following:

1. The user clicks a "Reply" button
2. The user then clicks another "Reply" button
3. The first clicked "Reply" button is no longer visible

If the above is the case, the issue is that you're not "unhiding" the first "Reply" button clicked (in step 1), when you click the second "Reply" button in step 2.

```
$('.comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
    // HERE - CHECK TO SEE IF A REPLY BUTTON WAS CLICKED BEFORE!
    // IS IT STILL HIDDEN?
        // YES -> UNHIDE
        // NO -> CONTINUE

    var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
    commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').hide();
    $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();
});
```

There are a few ways you can fix this. One quick way is just showing the `.comment-reply-link` before you call `$( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();`

Something like:

```
$('.comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
    var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
    commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').hide();
    $('#cancel-comment-reply-link').parent().find('.comment-reply-link').show()
    $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();
});
```

Other ways are applying some sort of "state" to the reply element (a class, data attribute), and querying that (to show when you click another reply later).

Answer (score -2):

I think it's because you're using an id `'#cancel-comment-reply-link'`

 Try instead of unsing a id like

```html
<div id="cancel-comment-reply-link"></div>
```

TO

```html
<div class="cancel-comment-reply-link"></div>
```

Because an id is unique to a DOMelement according to [MDN.Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

And change the script to:

```html
<script>
    jQuery( function( $ ){
        $( '.comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
            var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
            commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').hide();
            $( '.cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();
        } );
        $( '.cancel-comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
            var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
            commentContainer.find('.cancel-comment-reply-link').insertAfter(this).hide();
            commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').show();
        } );
    } );
</script>
```