# Check to see if the answer has already been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76135089/21663731), they gave an answer, the answer is a question for me again.

How can I check if the reply button has already been clicked or not?

```
<script>
    jQuery( function( $ ){
        $( '.comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
            // HERE - CHECK TO SEE IF A REPLY BUTTON WAS CLICKED BEFORE!
            // IS IT STILL HIDDEN?
                // YES -> UNHIDE
                // NO -> CONTINUE
            var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
            commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').hide();
            $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).parent().find( '.comment-reply-link' ).show();
            $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();
        } );
        $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
            var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
            commentContainer.find('#cancel-comment-reply-link').insertAfter(this).hide();
            commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').show();
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what you can do:

```
jQuery( function( $ ){
    var replyClicked = false;
    $( '.comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
        if (!replyClicked) {
            // State - first time the reply button is clicked
            replyClicked = true;
        } else {
            // State - reply button has already been clicked
            // do your work here
        }
        var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
        commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').hide();
        $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).parent().find( '.comment-reply-link' ).show();
        $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).insertAfter( this ).show();
    } );
    $( '#cancel-comment-reply-link' ).on( 'click', function(){
        var commentContainer = $(this).closest('.comment_container');
        commentContainer.find('#cancel-comment-reply-link').insertAfter(this).hide();
        commentContainer.find('.comment-reply-link').show();
    } );
} );
```

Comment: **existentia**, You have helped me a lot, thank you.

Comment: @widkoinflm u're welcome :)